# Beginner array iteration & error code interpretation

Tags: ruby, arrays, error-handling

I kept getting the following error. After some research I assumed this is because my array access was throwing the error due to (mistakenly) having a NIL value.

```
my_solution.rb:24:in `count_between': undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass       
(NoMethodError) from my_solution.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

I'm new to reading error codes, so perhaps that's where I went wrong. But it got tunnel vision on line **24**, as the error suggested. However I couldn't fix it, so out of desperation I wound up randomly changing the (<=) on line **23** to just (<). This fixed it.

1. Why did this fix it? My only guess is that originally using (<=) made it iterate "too far" and thus somehow returned NIL?
2. Why did the error code say it was the element on line 24 causing the issue, when it was actually the element on line 23? I'm new and am trying to be less intimated by error codes, so this was a curious experience.

Thanks for any guidance.

```
# count_between is a method with three arguments:
#   1. An array of integers
#   2. An integer lower bound
#   3. An integer upper bound
#
# It returns the number of integers in the array between the lower and upper          
# bounds,
# including (potentially) those bounds.
#
# If +array+ is empty the method should return 0
# Your Solution Below:

def count_between(list_of_integers, lower_bound, upper_bound)
if list_of_integers.empty?
   return 0
else
   count = 0
   index = 0

   ##line 23## 
   while index <= list_of_integers.length

   ##line24## 
       if list_of_integers[index] >= lower_bound &&    
       list_of_integers[index] <= upper_bound

            count += 1
            index += 1
       else
            index += 1
       end
    end 
 return count
end
end

puts count_between([1,2,3], 0, 100)
```

Comment: [1, 2, 3].length => 3 but the array index starts at 0, so to iterate through an array you would do while i < array.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last index that's `<= list_of_integers.length` is outside of the array, since the first index of an array is 0 and the last is `array.length - 1`.

The reason your error says line 24 is that line 23 works fine --- it just computes that the value of `index` is less than or equal to the the length of the array. Once you try and reference the element at that index in the array, however, it's assigned nil - and you can't perform a `>=` operation on nil.

One thing that might be helpful here is firing up an irb. If you try to reference an element that's out of bounds, you'll just get nil. If you try and perform an operation (that's not listed in `nil.methods`) on that same reference, it'll throw the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for spelling it out, makes perfect sense. Lesson learned: be mindful of iterating through arrays, and be mindful that while an error is found on a specific line, that the "source" of the error can come from elsewhere. Regarding IRB, I'm actually pretty new to it as well. I'd love to try what you've mentioned. The problem I find is that it feels tedious to type code out line-by-line in IRB, then if I make a mistake, I think I have to type it all over again? Whereas in Sublime Text I just edit the line and re-run the program. I'm probably approaching it wrong though. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: No you're right it can be tedious if you want to plug in a lot of lines, but it can be helpful to get quick, targeted feedback on a miniature version of your problem. For example, if you created an array and stored it in a variable, tried referencing an index that's out of bounds, then tried performing an operation on that same reference - that'd be 3 lines, but it'd demonstrate how each step in your problem went down.